# Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS - Swift Literals

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I made a simple program to test Swift integer literals. I have not studied Swift much yet. I copied the code from a web page and renamed the variables. I get:

> Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0). The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.

```
import UIKit

let desimaali = 42
let binaari = 0b101010
let oktaali = 0o52
let heksa = 0x2A
```

I have tried replacing all the white space characters manually with normal spaces in case there are special hidden characters, but that doesn't seem to be the case. What could be the problem? A bug in Swift Playgrounds? (OS X 10.11.6 and Xcode 8.2.1.)

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution from here: [Xcode 8 error when start MyPlayground. How to fix it?](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/63228)

Add more lines to the end and delete those lines:

> I had the same issue and tried adding an additional line to the default playground text (the code that a new playground creates by default). Same error but then I went to the end of the file, backspaced over everything up to the end of the line with var string = "Hello, playground" and hit Enter and the playground worked! Somehow forcing XCode to reread the file without a bunch of trailing blank lines fixed it? Weird.

Comment: Thank you!  Using  OS X 10.13.5 and Xcode 9.4.1.  This solved my problem.